# Wordpress elementor form trigger javascript on popup that opens after submitting form

Tags: wordpress, forms, elementor, wordpress-rest-api

In Wordpress elementor form I want to trigger JavaScript on a popup that opens after submitting form. But the popup code loads when the page loads I guess and so the script is firing before the popup opens up.

For now, I have added the script in custom JS of the popup.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried. provide some codes.

Comment: I have just added the script in an html code block inside the page.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.